# AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON <FIELD> is preventing the program from retrieving data

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm still in the learning phase of SAP ABAP, so please bear with me. So I am trying to create a report that will retrieve data from vbak table, but there are some conditions: 
1) Enable and Disable radio buttons.
2) Use a "AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON " statement.
3) Checkbox'organize' (To print out the data in a presentable way)
4) Checkbox 'Download as a Text File' to download the data as a text file.

My Code:

```
REPORT z_testingdemo.
TABLES: vbak.


SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b1 WITH FRAME NO INTERVALS.
PARAMETERS: rb_on RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.
PARAMETERS: rb_off RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.
PARAMETERS: p_name TYPE char15.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_vbeln FOR vbak-vbeln.
PARAMETERS: c_check AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT 'X'.
PARAMETERS: c_check2 AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1.



AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.
  IF rb_on IS INITIAL.
    MESSAGE 'Please Press ENABLE to ENABLE the FIELDS' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDIF.

"--------I don't really know why this part didn't work -----------

*  IF rb_off = 'X'.
*    screen-active = 0.
*    modify screen.
*  ELSE.
*    screen-active = 1.
*    modify screen.
*  ENDIF.
"------------------------------------------------------------------


  TYPES: BEGIN OF itab,
           vbeln TYPE vbak-vbeln,
           vkorg TYPE vbak-vkorg,
           vtweg TYPE vbak-vtweg,
           spart TYPE vbak-spart,
         END OF itab.

  DATA: wa_ma TYPE itab,
        it_ma TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF itab.

  SELECT vbeln vkorg vtweg spart
                           FROM vbak
                           INTO TABLE it_ma
                           WHERE vbeln IN s_vbeln.

  IF sy-subrc = 0 AND c_check = '' AND c_check2 = ''.
    LOOP AT it_ma INTO wa_ma.
      WRITE : / wa_ma-vbeln, wa_ma-vkorg , wa_ma-vtweg, wa_ma-spart.
    ENDLOOP.
  ELSEIF sy-subrc = 0 AND c_check = 'X' AND c_check2 = ''.
    LOOP AT it_ma INTO wa_ma.
      WRITE : / wa_ma-vbeln,  17 wa_ma-vkorg ,  37 wa_ma-vtweg,  51 wa_ma-spart.
    ENDLOOP.
  ELSEIF sy-subrc = 0 AND c_check2 = 'X'.

    CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_DOWNLOAD'
      EXPORTING
        filename              = 'C:/REPORT4.TXT'
        write_field_separator = ','
      TABLES
        data_tab              = it_ma.

  ELSEIF sy-subrc = 0 AND c_check = '' AND c_check2 = 'X'.
  ENDIF.


TOP-OF-PAGE .
  PERFORM display_heading .
FORM display_heading.
  WRITE : / sy-uline .
  WRITE: / 'REPORT 4'.
  IF c_check = 'X'.
    WRITE:  / .
    WRITE : /'For Mr./Mrs.: ', p_name.
    WRITE : /'SALES DOCUMENT', 17 'SALES ORGANIZATION',  37 'DISTRIBUTION',  51 'CHANN. DIVISION'.
    WRITE : / sy-uline .
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

I mean, without the AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON  statement, it mostly works. But the AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON  is one of the conditions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start your code without a `START-OF_SELECTION`.

By default, your report start with the event `START-OF_SELECTION`, but with `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` you define another event and your code doesn't start at `START-OF_SELECTION`.

So you have two solutions:

- Move your code `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` below your main code.
- Add a `START-OF_SELECTION` before your main code.

And as vwegert already mentioned, to change the setting on the selection screen, you need a `LOOP AT SCREEN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the settings of the fields, you need to do so in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`, and you will need to use a `LOOP AT SCREEN` statement to iterate through the fields.